# Can Pandas infer DataFrame names?

Tags: python, pandas

For example, instead of writing:

```
cast[(cast['title'] == "Hamlet") & (cast['year'] == 1921)]
```

is it possible to write something along the lines of this:

```
cast[('title' == "Hamlet") & ('year' == 1921)]
```

and have Pandas infer the DataFrame name? I know the first is creating a boolean Series and that's how Pandas works, but I'm hoping there's a way to write what looks to me to be cleaner code and have it still work in these cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [pd.query](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#the-query-method-experimental) like

```
cast.query('(title == "Hamlet") & (year == 1921)')
```

or without the brackets

```
cast.query('title == "Hamlet" & year == 1921')
```

Comment: Wow this is a nice surprise.  And it seems more performant: %timeit cast[(cast['name'] == "Cary Grant") & (cast['year'] >= 1940) & (cast['year'] <= 1949) & (cast['n'] == 1)].count() gave me 334ms per loop, while %timeit cast.query('name == "Cary Grant" & year >= 1940 & year <= 1949 & n == 1').count() gave me 128ms per loop!  Any reason why I wouldn't want to use .query() for all my work?

Comment: @user1956609 the drawback to query is that you can't have spaces in the column names (AFAIK).